# getting and adding Inkstrokes

Tags: c#, xaml, types, uwp, inkcanvas

I am trying to create a note app myself. I want the app to have several pages, each with their own 'InkCanvas'. I've managed this, but whenever I leave the page the 'collection/list' of 'InkStrokes' gets cleared.

My solution is to create a list of 'InkStrokes'. Save that list in the pages.xaml.cs and then load that list into the 'InkCanvas' whenever the page is navigated onto again.

Here I am trying to first get the strokes and then add them back:

```
var strokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();

        foreach (var stroke in strokes)
        {
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStroke(stroke);

        }
```

I've also tried this without luck:

```
private IEnumerable<InkStroke> pageStrokes;

      pageStrokes = new IEnumerable<InkStroke> //Line continues
      inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();

      inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStrokes(pageStrokes);
```

I suspect my problem is due to mismatched types of data. It would be very helpful if anyone answering this could explain a little about a possible solution and why it works.

In advance, many thanks to you kind internet strangers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My solution is to create a list of 'InkStrokes'. Save that list in the pages.xaml.cs and then load that list into the 'InkCanvas' whenever the page is navigated onto again.

You can save the `StrokeContainer` instead of saving `Strokes`. I made a basic demo and save the `StrokeContainer` to Application Resource and load them in `OnNavigatedTo` and it works.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //if the mainpage resource exists then load the container
    if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("mainpage"))
    {
        var resource = Application.Current.Resources["mainpage"];
        myCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer = (InkStrokeContainer)resource;
    }
}
//I save the StrokeContainer in a button click event
private void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("mainpage", myCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer));
}
```

And here is my demo project: [SaveStrokeSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/SaveStrokeSample).

Comment: Thank you for this. Ironically I had just now found a solution and came to post my answer, but this one was so much cleaner and easier. Mine involved a separate strokecontainer, multiple lines for type conversions and just other mess. You're awesome!